# How i can achieve home page like this <http://www.giantstepsmedias.com/>

Tags: css, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

I can achieve the background particles using examples from three.js,

How i can achieve the N shape they have made using particles and the hover effect also

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Right-click --> Inspect Element.

Comment: You cant! If you really want to make this wesbiste learn WebGL and HTML5 Canvas

Comment: @jbutler483 yeah i tried that they are having minified js with minified variables,functions names which is hard to understand and i formatted there js its around 7000 lines god help me its hard to understand

Comment: @Eirenaios yeah i am exploring three.js ,using Three.shape() i can have shape using particles but i need to explore it more

Comment: go explore https://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl

Comment: searching 'particles' in codepen brought me to this: http://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/EDaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving such an effect is not easy, but if you want a start, here is a simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fezany2x/4/

The trick is to avoid refreshing the whole canvas. Instead, just erase your particles and repaint them again:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#004";
boxes.forEach(
    function(box) {
        ctx.fillRect(box.x - 2, box.y - 2, 8, 8);
    }
);

ctx.fillStyle = "white";
boxes.forEach(
    function(box) {
        ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, 4, 4);
    }
);
```